# Protractor with ng-apimock is not adding ngapimockid to all http requests of test

Tags: angular, protractor

We're using `ng-apimock` to test our angular application. For returning specific data sets in certain tests, we use `ngApiMock.selectScenario`
When i look at the http request of the selectScenario (in a tcp monitor) i see a header is added with key `ngapimockid` (and a generated value).

However when executing the test, I noticed that the `ngapimockid` was often not specified in the header (or as cookie), resulting in receiving other data than setup in the `ngApiMock.selectScenario`.

For example an http request during execution of test (with the ngapimockid):

```
GET /somerandomuri HTTP/1.1
cookie: ngapimockid=46206072-c0e3-44f3-b93c-4e1658db9d46
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
referer: http://localhost:49152/
user-agent: Moz.......
```

And an example of an http request during the same test execution with no `ngapimockid` (to same endpoint):

```
GET /somerandomuri HTTP/1.1
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
referer: http://localhost:49152/
user-agent: Moz.......
```

I figured the `ngapimockid` is for supporting parallel testing with different scenarios but i can't understand why it's often not added during the testexecution.
I think the following part of the `protractor.mock.js` is responsible for adding the hook that adds the `ngapimockid` to the tests http requests:

```
/** Make sure that angular uses the ngapimock identifier for the requests. */
browser.getProcessedConfig().then((config) => {
    // As of protractor 5.0.0 the flag config.useAllAngular2AppRoots has been deprecated, to let protractor tell
    // ngApimock that Angular 2 is used a custom object needs to be provided with the angular version in it
    // See: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-2
    if (config.useAllAngular2AppRoots || ('ngApimockOpts' in config && config.ngApimockOpts.angularVersion > 1)) {
        // angular 2 does not have addMockModule support @see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3092
        // fallback to cookie
        require('hooker').hook(browser, 'get', {
            post: function (result) {
                return result.then(function () {
                    // Since protractor 5.0.0 the addCookie is an object, see
                    // https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500
                    try {
                        return browser.manage().addCookie({name: "ngapimockid", value: ngapimockid});
                    } catch (error) {
                        // Fallback protractor < 5.0.0
                        return browser.manage().addCookie('ngapimockid', ngapimockid);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Angular 2+ lacks addMockModule, but hybrid apps still need this
        if(!!config.ngApimockOpts.hybrid) {
            browser.addMockModule('ngApimock', ProtractorMock, {ngapimockid: ngapimockid});
        }
    } else {
        browser.addMockModule('ngApimock', ProtractorMock, {'ngapimockid': ngapimockid})
    }
```

Again not understanding why it won't work for all http requests. Am I missing some crucial config/setup that explains this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking again at the tcpmonitor i noticed the requests that have no `ngapimockid` were the first http requests after selecting the scenario (in the `Background` of the `feature` file) and before the first step in my test (`Scenario outline`).

So i suspected the opening of the page happens outside protractor's domain. (Even though i see it happen in the tcpmonitor after the scenario selection.)

I added a step in the `Background` where the page is refreshed and in that http call i do see the `ngapimockid` in the headers of the request. So for now i fixed it by adding a step `And I have opened the page` after the scenario selection that refreshes the page.

Part of the resulting feature file:

```
Feature: Create XXX

    I want to be able to create new XXX
    So that we can do something exciting

    Background:
        Given the "empty" XXX set
        And I have opened the page


    Scenario Outline: Create XXX
```

Part of the resulting step file:

```
defineSupportCode(function({ Before, Given }) {

    Given(/^I have opened the page$/, openPage);
    async function openPage() {
        await browser.refresh();
    }
});
```